# Angular6 : Wait nested call API before display an array angular material

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

### Current behavior

1. call api with my http service for get all users
2. for each user (loop), call api (other entity) with my http service for get all locations of user.
3. i need associate locations (return by request) with his user.
4. display an array (angular material mat-tab)
5. My array is empty or missing locations in each user object...

### Expected behavior

I need build an array with users and his locations before print mat-tab.

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

In my component :

```
public userWithLocations          = [];

ngOnInit () {
        this.loadData();    
    }

loadData() {
        let that = this;
        // get all users
        this.httpSrv.getAllUsers()
            .subscribe(allUser => {

                for (let user in allUser) {

                    let currentUser = allUser[user];

                    // get locations by user
                    this.httpSrv.getLocationsByUser(allUser[user]['_id'])
                        .subscribe((locations) => {

                            currentUser.nb_location = locations;

                            that.userWithLocations.push(currentUser);
                    })
                }

                console.log(that.userWithLocations); // => []

                // Here i need my array with for each user an attribute with locations count

                // init MatTableDataSource dataSource only when receive data (NOT BEFORE)!
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(that.userWithLocations);
                // init paginator
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                // // init sort
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            });
    }
```

In my service (http) :

```
    // Users requests
    getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
        // return Observable
        return this.http.get(this.apiURL + 'users');
    }

    getLocationsByUser(id): Observable<any> {
        // return Observable
        return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/locations/' + id)
            .pipe(map(locations => { return this.size(locations)}));
    }

    // Object length
    size(obj) {
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
        }

        return size;
    };
```

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

i am young developer, beginner in angular 6 and i try to learn how to do nested call api with rxjs for my job.

### Environment

```
Angular version: X.Y.Z

> Angular CLI: 6.0.8
> Node: 10.4.0
> OS: darwin x64
> Angular: 6.0.4
> 
> Package                           Version
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
> @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
> @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
> @angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
> @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
> @angular/animations               6.0.5
> @angular/cdk                      6.2.1
> @angular/cli                      6.0.8
> @angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.15
> @angular/material                 6.2.1
> @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
> @schematics/angular               0.6.8
> @schematics/update                0.6.8
> rxjs                              6.2.1
> typescript                        2.7.2
> webpack                           4.8.3

Browser:
- [x] Chrome (desktop) Version 68.0.3440.84
- [ ] Chrome (Android) version XX
- [ ] Chrome (iOS) version XX
- [ ] Firefox version XX
- [ ] Safari (desktop) version XX
- [ ] Safari (iOS) version XX
- [ ] IE version XX
- [ ] Edge version XX

For Tooling issues:
- Node: 10.4.0
- Platform:  Mac

Others:
```

Comment: We can help if you face an issue. If you simply don't know how to do what you want, I suggest you read the documentation : https://angular.io/

Comment: I have no find something like that in the angular doc =s

Comment: Waiting for an HTTP call to finish before displaying the data ? Then you didn't read the documentation properly : [**conditonal display with ngIf**](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#conditional-display-with-ngif)

Comment: Dude pls read my post... I don't waiting for an simply HTTP call... i need understand how to do something in nested request with second depend of each item receive in the first request... 
Angular-tour-of-heroes tutorial no explain that.

Comment: I've read your post, your english is terrible and I don't understand the issue you're facing. And given the response you validated, this was in RxJS documentation. Anyway, you have resolved your issue, so great, good luck with your project !

Comment: Yes my english is terrible =s

Answer (score 3):

One issue in your code is that you subscribe within a subscribe. This is something that has to be avoided. Is a clear sign of misusing RxJs.

The right way with RxJs is more something like this

```
this.httpSrv.getAllUsers()
.pipe(
  map(users => from(users)),
  mergeMap(user => this.httpSrv.getLocationsByUser(user[_id])
                   .pipe(
                      tap(locations => user.nb_location = locations;
                   )
           ),
  toArray()
)
.subscribe(userWithLocations => {// do what you need to do})
```

Basically what this code does is

- call your first service to get the array of users
- transform the array into an Observable of users (i.e. a stream of
  users) with `map` and `from`
- for each user, call the second service and set the locations of each
  user with the returned result - this is done with `mergeMap` and the
  following piped `tap`
- Eventually transform the stream of users in an array with `toArray`
- Now you can subscribe and what you obtain is an Array of users filled
  with their locations with which you can do whatever you need to do

The problem in you original code is that, due to the asynchronous nature of http calls, when you exit the `for` loop, the various calls to fetch the locations have not been executed. They will return their result some time later. In the meantime, your `userWithLocations` is clearly an empty array.

I suggest you to spend some time in looking at RxJs and understand its mechanics. Even if not in the context of Angular, [this is an article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c) that explains how the operators I have talked about before work.